# For loop with files with Python

Tags: python, sikuli-ide

I have this code:

```
import os

directory = "JeuDeDonnees"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print("File is: "+filename)
```

This code run and prints files name in a VSCode/Python environment.

However, when I run it in Sikuli-IDE I got this error:

```
[error] SyntaxError ( "no viable alternative at input 'for'",  )
```

How can I make this `for` loop run or is there an alternative that can work?

Comment: You are somehow running the script with something other than Python - that error message format seems to be associated with Apache Cassandra.  Either you don't have a `.py` extension on the file, or your IDE is misconfigured.

Comment: How can this be possible ? The file is `.py` , and IDE is well configured, working with Jython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found ;
Basically, in my Sikuli-IDE environnement, there's layers of Python, Java, Jython... interlocking each other so the Path finding was tedious.

```
src_file_path = inspect.getfile(lambda: None) #The files we're in
folder = os.path.dirname(src_file_path)       # The folder we're in
directory = folder + "\JeuDeDonnees"          # Where we wanna go
for filename in os.listdir(directory)         # Get the files
    print(filename)
```

We're telling the Path where we are with the current file, get the folder we're in, then moving to `"\JeuDeDonnees"` and the files.

Comment: You can improve your code with `__file__` and `pathlib`:
```python
from pathlib import Path
src_file_path = Path(__file__)
parent_dir = src_file_path.parent
directory = parent_dir / "JeuDeDonnees"
for filename in directory.iterdir():
    print(filename)
```